# alert condition over variables in datadog

Tags: datadog

How can I create a threshold alert by comparing aggregate of 2 metrics ? For example, if m1=[2,3,1,5] and m2=[6,7], I want to create an alert when sum(m1) > sum(m2).  sum method here I assume will add all the data points returned by a query.

From what I have observed, datadog flow of alert creating is like, define the metric  -> set alert condition on metric. That is, it looks like the alert condition will be some condition on metric data type only.

But I am looking for something like storing the aggregate of metrics in a variables and comparing those variables. How can it be done in datadog ?